# Handling drag over event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am implementing html5 drag and drop (for the first time). I have the following ng-repeat where the drop target is the outer div:

```
<div ng-repeat="chapter in chapters" class="chapter " ondrop="drop_handler(event);" ondragover="dragover_handler(event);">
    <div><bold>{{chapter.title}}</bold></div>
    <div>{{chapter.text}}</div>
</div>
```

However the dragover event is fired also for the inner elements (as `event.target`).

In my `dragover_handler()` I need to get hold of the outer div so that I can, for example, set a background-color. How can I achieve this?

I could do this by specifying a ondragover for each inner element and then selecting the outer div, but that is really ugly as it needs the ondragover attr for each inner element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `node.addEventListener('dragover', handler_func, true)` instead of element attribute.

The 3rd function to `addEventListener` turns on event capturing and this allows events fired from child elements to be sent to specified `handler_func`.